# Populating a list depending on what is clicked on a table

Tags: html, button, click, populate

I’m quite new in html and have just very very basic knowledge of it. I’m trying to prepare a small demo for my department on how the visuals for a project should work.
What I basically want to do is populate a sentence depending on what is clicked on a table. So far I unfortunately was just able to do the resource part but not implement the populating and clicking functionality perhaps someone can help.

The resource data for the sentence to be populated is:

```
<li>Stage 2 phrase: <br/>  “<b>FROM</b> <font color="'#043345">< City 1 ></font> <b>TO</b> <font color="'#043345">< City 2 ></font> <b>VIA</b> <font color="'#043345">< City 3 ></font>”<br/><br/>
```

The resource data for the table is:

```
 <br/><table border="1" style="width:100%"><tr>
    <td>Chicago</td>
    <td>Istanbul</td> 
    <td>Budapest</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>Copenhagen</td>
    <td>Lisbon</td> 
    <td>Sydney</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>Washington</td>
    <td>Singapore</td> 
    <td>Barcelona</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>Helsinki</td>
    <td> Next </td> 
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
</table><br/><br/>
```

What I want to do is make the city names as buttons in the table “clickcable” and after clicking make the city button remain in a specific color depending on if it was clicked first, second or third for example:
First city clicked will be green
Second city clicked will be yellow
Third city clicked will be red
When I click the first city the first placeholder (city 1) in the sentence should be populated with the first clicked city.

The next button in the table should clear all 3 cities clicked and give the option to restart once again. Thanks for your time! Cheers

Comment: You will need javascript for this. HTML is not a programming, but a hyper-text **markup** language.

Comment: If you want to learn how to do this, you could have a look at the [Javascript Basics Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics#Events).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this something you looking for ?

```
var cityIter = 0;
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
function clickCity(n) {
  switch(cityIter){
    case 0:     
document.getElementById(cityIter).style.backgroundColor = 'green';
      break;
    case 1:
document.getElementById(cityIter).style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
      break;
    case 2:
document.getElementById(cityIter).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById(cityIter).value = buttons[n].innerHTML; 
  cityIter+=1;
}
```

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNqmBJ)

Its rather simple answer but still hope I help you :)

Comment: This is great! Just what i need. How can i add a "NEXT" button to clear the placeholders and start again?